# How to bind the repeater which is placed in Web User Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, webusercontrol

I have a webuser control having repeater control inside it like below.

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="repeaterInvoicesPaid" runat="server">
        </asp:Repeater>
```

I just dragged it to my data.aspx page.Now i have a method inside data.cs C# file which is returning the data from table .i want to ask ,how to bind the repeater(which is inside the user control)?

it will be binded inside data.cs file or web user control's own C# file.?

And please tell me how to access the repeater id from user control inside data.cs file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As for question 1: You can either

- expose the repeater (see question 3) or
- expose the datasource

Personally I am in favour of the last option

For databinding options, you can choose to expose the built-in databind method or you can databind when the source is set.

Exposing the datasource could be done like this

```
public static object RepeaterDataSource {
    get { return repeater.DataSource; }
    set { repeater.DataSource = value; }
}
```

or make a method to set it, to allow manipulation upon setting, like databinding.

---

Question 2: The actual binding always happens where the repeater is. If you need an OnItemDataBound handler, then that one will be in the usercontrol's code-behind, regardless of where you bind it from. You can however expose that too, but I see no reason to do so.

---

Question 3: If you want the id, then I assume the client id. You can get that with something like this

```
public static string RepeaterClientID {
    get { return theRepeater.ClientID; }
}
```

Although I'm not sure that's what you actually mean. If you want a reference instead, then

```
public static Repeater TheRepeater {
    get { return theRepeater; }
    set { theRepeater = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create object of user control

UserControl usr = Page.FindControl("usercontrolID");
Repeator rept = usr.FindControl("repeatorControlID");

rept.DataScourse= Datatbale;
rept.DataBind();

Answer (score 0):

You could always make a public property in your user control that returns the repeater.